# NLTK: Converting from tree values to Lambda function notation

Tags: python, lambda, nltk, context-free-grammar

I am trying to convert a sentence into a lambda function notation such as the one seen http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html in section 4.2. Using code I can make the sentence be converted into the semantic values and parse the sentence using context free grammar but what are ways to convert a sentence into lambda notations.

```
import nltk
grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
  S -> NP VP
  VP -> V NP 
  V -> "is" 
  Adj -> "Chewing"
  Coj -> "and"
  Nom -> Adj Nom | N
  NP ->  Nom Coj NP | N
  Det -> "a" | "an" | "the" | "my"
  N -> "gum" | "candy" | "thrilling"
  P -> "in" | "on" | "by" | "with"
  """)
sent = "Chewing gum and candy is thrilling".split()
rd_parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(grammar, )
for tree in rd_parser.parse(sent):
    print (tree)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: You have to write your own semantic grammar. There is just no easy way to map a CFG to lambda-calculus.

**Longer answer**:

From CFG, the closest you get to a semantic tree is to specify semantic features for non-terminals and the SQL CFG example is a good guide to how to go about doing that, see section 1.1. from http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html:

```
>>> nltk.data.show_cfg('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
% start S
S[SEM=(?np + WHERE + ?vp)] -> NP[SEM=?np] VP[SEM=?vp]
VP[SEM=(?v + ?pp)] -> IV[SEM=?v] PP[SEM=?pp]
VP[SEM=(?v + ?ap)] -> IV[SEM=?v] AP[SEM=?ap]
NP[SEM=(?det + ?n)] -> Det[SEM=?det] N[SEM=?n]
PP[SEM=(?p + ?np)] -> P[SEM=?p] NP[SEM=?np]
AP[SEM=?pp] -> A[SEM=?a] PP[SEM=?pp]
NP[SEM='Country="greece"'] -> 'Greece'
NP[SEM='Country="china"'] -> 'China'
Det[SEM='SELECT'] -> 'Which' | 'What'
N[SEM='City FROM city_table'] -> 'cities'
IV[SEM=''] -> 'are'
A[SEM=''] -> 'located'
P[SEM=''] -> 'in'
```

Mapping CFG to lambda-calculus and vice versa or learning both from text is a still a research worthy work, so there's no clear way to do it for now.

See http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2052254 and
http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/ictai/2008/3440/02/3440b135-abs.html